# Unable to execute printf command by using formatter and argument variable

Tags: bash

I am trying to store all the printf formatter and arguments into their own respective variables to be execute later. Example code:

```
var="abc123"
var2="def 456"
printfArgument=$var" "$var2

formatter="%-10s"
formatter2="%-10s"
printfFormatter=$formatter" "$formatter2"\n"

printf "$printfFormatter" $printfArgument
```

output:

```
abc123     def       
456
```

It seems like the space in var2 causes the 456 to display improperly. Any way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You're correct; the space in `var2` is being used for word-splitting. `printf` is receiving 3 arguments after the format string: `abc123`, `def`, and `456`. The first two fill the two format specifiers for the first line of output. Since there is a remaining argument, the format string is used again to produce the second line of output.

You need to use an array for `printfArgument`:

```
printfArgument=( "$var" "$var2" )
printf "$printfFormatter" "${printfArgument[@]}"
```

or just use `var` and `var2` separately:

```
printf "$printfFormatter" "$var" "$var2"
```